# Distance between two places latitude longitude are different with Google API and maps.google.com

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API for distance calculation, see my code:

I have passed lat long in URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=22.73931300,75.89195600&destination=22.74290400%2C75.89317200
```

**Output of above URL is:**

```
"distance" : {
                  "text" : "3.2 km",
                  "value" : 3157
               }
```

Now same thing I have checked with google map:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'22.73931300,75.89195600'/'22.74290400,75.89317200'/@22.7411227,75.8903586,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!4m8!1m3!2m2!1d75.891956!2d22.739313!1m3!2m2!1d75.893172!2d22.742904
```

**Output of above URL is: 400 m**

Now we can see the difference in both and both are using google map API. Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longer distance is the driving distance and includes several U-turns.  The shorter distance looks like walking directions to me.  If I change it to driving directions, it gives a longer distance:

[link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'22.73931300,75.89195600'/'22.74290400,75.89317200'/@22.7413015,75.8881004,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m10!4m9!1m3!2m2!1d75.891956!2d22.739313!1m3!2m2!1d75.893172!2d22.742904!3e0)

If you want the same distance, use the same travel mode.